# htaccess file - how do these redirects work?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

it's really difficult to understand htaccess's work, I have this code:

```
#Remove slash on the end
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301]

#Don't use .php extension in URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php

#All the directories should be redirected to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . index [R=301]
```

Structure of my root folder: `index.php`, `.htaccess` and `dir` directory with `test.php` file inside.

I know that this file re-executes multiple times until the changes in URL are over, so if I'm writing `mysite.ru/index/dir/` to address bar for example (I use existing index file as directory, otherwise, if I use words that aren't related to existing file names, it's works), I'm expecting 404 page (Slash removes, dir.php doesn't exist, index/dir doesn't exist, file executes again, URL didn't changed and it's over), but I'm getting 500 error and 10 redirects in error.log file. Something wrong with `.htacess` file, and I can't understang what.

Comment: That request ends up calling index.php Activate the RewriteLog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `END` flag or `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` condition to prevent the infinite rewrite loop error.

END flag works on Apache version 2.4 or greater

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [END]
```

The following condition works on all versions

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php
```

The reason why you got internal server error (Too many redirects) is because your rule rewrites the same request multiple times.  Your rule gets triggered when you request `/filename/blabla` .
Since the `/filename/blabla` doesn't map to an existing file  your condition  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f`  only checks the first path segment `/filename` . the condition is met and the rule gets triggered in loop.

Comment: as I understand it, if the filename in full path doesn't exist, `REQUEST_FILENAME` will check every segment from beginning to end, and if I want to prevent this, I add `[END]` flag, which stops further checking of the condition (checking every segment if file doesn't exist in that case) and if exists, finishes execution of htaccess?